# How do I calculate the NPV(of DCF) of a mutual fund investment?

Tags: stocks, mutual-funds, calculation

How do I measure the yearly cash-flow of a lumpsum mutual fund investment (or an equity investment) (provided I am not cashing out each year), also what do I take as the discount factor?

Comment: If you aren't cashing out or depositing in, there is no cash flow.... are you sure you are asking the right question?